# Is manually requesting buffering necessary?

Tags: c

Is it necessary to call functions like `setbuf()` and `setvbuf()` when I open `FILE` streams to adjust buffering?
Isn't I/O buffering handled automatically?

Comment: What do you mean by "mandatory?"

Comment: I mean is it necessary, sorry for my bad english

Comment: Your english is fine! But again, what do you mean by "necessary?" Necessary/mandatory _for what?_

Comment: Is it Necessary/mandatory to call buffering functions like setbuf() and setvbuf() when opening FILE streams

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, buffering is handled automatically, but **maybe not in the fashion you want or need**.

You might want flushing on each write, only on newline, only on full buffer, and the default is wrong for your case.

Or you might want a bigger buffer for efficiency.

In all those cases, adjust the default.
Though, in general the default is sensible, and can be left alone.

Here a case where the automatic sniffer failed badly:
[printf statement is not executing before scanf statement in netbean](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24344497)

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not necessary or mandatory.

You would only call `setbuf` or `setvbuf` if the default buffering for that stream is not what you want.  For example, standard output is normally *line-buffered*, so output won't be flushed until the buffer is full or you send a newline character.  If you want standard output to be unbuffered (all output shows up immediately), *then* you would need to use `setbuf` or `setvbuf`.