# Interleaving input and output when executing in the Eclipse IDE

Tags: c++

Do you know why eclipse console first executes gets function and then cout?
I have this code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  char str[80];
  cout << "Enter any string: ";
  gets(str);
  cout << "Here is your string: ";
  cout << str;
  return 0;
}
```

```
It's just a test
Enter any string: Here is your string: It's just a test
```

P.S. This program works as it should if i'm using DOS console.

Comment: You really don't want to mix C and C++ I/O if you can avoid it.

Comment: @PaulR: That's not an error though, unlike using `gets` under any circumstances.

Comment: MinGW. endl and flush() work well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add endl after using cout. If will add a newline and flush the stream.

```
  cout << "Enter any string: " << endl ;
  cout << "Here is your string: " << endl ;
```

And don't use gets!

Comment: Only use `endl` if you want both a newline and a flush. Use `'\n'` for just a newline or (as wanted here) `flush` for just a flush.

Comment: @2501 Thanks. It helped. I use gets() just because i'm reading Shildt and it gives advice that one of easiest way to read string from console is using gets() function.

Comment: @MikeSeymour http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26652682/edit There is an easier way.

Comment: @nikoliazekter: You should throw that book away and get one of these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242

Comment: Yep, the schildt book is infamously bad.

Comment: @Deduplicator I read Shildt book about Java and it teached me all i should know before learning libGDX. So i decided to read his book about C++.

Comment: @nikoliazekter: Unfortunately his book about C++ is *legendarily* bad.

Comment: @nikoliazekter: Well, I don't know how he is with Java, but no C or C++ programmer will touch his books about those languages with a ten-foot-pole. There are just too many glaring errors, unmentioned assumptions about the implementation (for all the examples he seems to have tested, he certainly only ever used one and the same implementation), and general bad advice in there. One of the famous quotes about it is that the price-difference between his book and the standard equals the value he removed (and that'S charitable).

Comment: @Deduplicator so can you recommend me good book for beginner?

Comment: @nikoliazekter Mike directed you to the SO-question with all the recommendations... Do not forget that man-pages generally are quite good. Though for the final word, download a draft of the C standard. When reading language-specifications and such, be aware that the language is quite deliberate, and when something cannot be proven, it probably does not hold. Thus, always prefer proper explanations with proof.

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse IDE is certainly not executing `gets` (Never use that function, it cannot be used safely and even the C standard banned it), but executing the compiler, linker and later the compiled program.

The problem is Eclipse IDE redirects the standard-handles, thus makeing the standard-library mis-identify those streams as "not an interactive device", which means full buffering is enabled, and automatic flushing of output on input is disabled.

The [solution is the same as for C streams](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344894/3204551):

Explicitly flush your output.

```
cout.flush(); // Just flush
cout << endl; // Output newline and flush
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that usually reading input _does_ automatically flush output buffers, but this is disabled by the redirection in this case. (In the C++ library this is controlled by `sync_with_stdio` and `basic_ostream::tie`)

Answer (score 1):

> *"Do you know why eclipse console first executes gets function and then cout?"*

The reason is that the output buffer isn't immediately flushed, when you call `operator<<()`. `std::endl` does so, as mentioned in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26652682/1413395), but also puts an extra newline, which you may not want to have there. The clean solution is to call `std::ostream::flush()` explicitly

```
  cout << "Enter any string: ";
  cout.flush(); // <<<<
  cin >> str;
  cout << "Here is your string: " << str << std::endl;
```